# Can't access Internet in Safe Mode (Windows XP SP3)

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update, safe-mode

I am receiving the error 0x80070020 when accessing Windows Update.  One of the solutions is to reboot in Safe Mode with networking support.  When I do this, my USB wireless broadband connection software will not connect to the Internet - the USB modem does not detect the wireless network.

Any ideas how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled my antivirus (Avast) and Windows Firewall, and I was able to connect properly to Windows Update.